# python import module multi-levels

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-import, python-module

I'm using Flask framework and would like to test a single class (not Flask app, and I've read the test documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/))

My folder structure is like below picture, and **init**.py for each folder.

[image]

But I tried all below but none of them works.

```
from ... import grouper
```

or

```
import reporting.dashboard.helpers.grouper
```

or

```
import dashboard
from dashboard.helpers.grouper import Grouper
```

Could anyone please give me some hints on how to include

> reporting/dashboard/helpers/grouper.py

in my test module located at

> reporting/tests/helpers/helper-test.py

?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try `from ...reporting.dashboard.helpers import grouper`?

Comment: Does the `helpers` directory have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @BrenBarn I tried but no luck, "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Comment: @thebjorn I just added one empty __init__.py under helps directory, but still not working...

Comment: @keypoint: You're probably running `helper-test.py` directly.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) and others you can find by googling that error message.

Comment: @BrenBarn oh yes you are right, I'm just running "python helper-test.py", I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: @BrenBarn I tried to run "python -m reporting.tests.helpers.helper-test.py" under directory reporting, but still no luck, "No module named reporting.tests.helpers.helper-test"...

Comment: Is the parent directory of your top-level `reporting` directory on `sys.path`?

Comment: @BrenBarn no...should I add it to sys.path ?

Comment: @keypoint: Yes (add the *parent* of `reporting` to `sys.path`).  You can't in general expect to be able to import anything that is not reachable from `sys.path`.

Comment: @BrenBarn is there an alternative way to do this? sys.path seems a bit hacky...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the cause. It's because the **__init__.py** under folder "reporting" is not empty, but doing some initiation operations for Flask app. When I **made this "__init__.py" a empty file**, the import was successful using

```
from reporting.dashboard.helpers.grouper import Grouper
```

Also, python-2.6 may **not recognize** "from xxx import yyyClass", but only "import xxxModule"

reference reading: 
[The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)